# Can i say “horridly work”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar

My classmate who always brags because he lived in america got into my team and we had to write an essay each one of us and it will affect the whole team if one of us gets a lower grade, so this kid wrote an essay with the worst grammar and spelling possible, he wrote house as “hause” and I claimed him to do it again because it was so bad but he lashed out and said it was correct and he wont do it again, so my team has decided to tell the teacher on email if we can expel him and while i was writing I wondered how can i say a horrible work in other words and “horridly work” came to mind but im not sure if i can say it that way or what other way can you say it.

Comment: Speaking of horrible work, you should always spell "I" in upper case, "America" is a proper noun (and should therefore be capitalized as well), and you might want to read some [tips](https://www.aims.edu/student/online-writing-lab/process/sentence-length) about [sentence length](http://web.mit.edu/juggler/www/ocw/ocw_lectures/class01/lecture_shorten_sentences.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to say his work is bad:

> He did horrid work.
>
> His work was not at all understandable.
>
> His work was **incoherent**.
>
> His work was poorly stuctured and worded.

**Horridly** is an adverb in most cases so it wouldn't work the way you wrote it.